# Non-section representation of an intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,\bar X,Y$ be arbitrary sets and $A\subseteq X\times Y$, $\bar A\subseteq \bar X\times Y$ be arbitrary as well. Denote:
$$
  A_x :=\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in A\}
$$
and similarly for $\bar A$. Consider a surjection $f:X\to \bar X$. If I would like to say that 
$$
  \bar A_{\bar x} = \bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}(\bar x)}A|_x \qquad \forall \bar x\in \bar X \tag{1}
$$
then I can equivalently write $\bar A = (f\parallel \mathrm{id}_Y)(A)$ where $(f\parallel \mathrm{id}_Y):(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),y)$. Such alternative short expression is more convenient than a section-wise definition $(1)$, and also allows pushing some properties of $A$ to $\bar A$. For example, if $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $\bar A$ is compact  - which would be more complicated to show using $(1)$ exclusively.

My question is: is that possible to use a similar trick for 
$$
\bar A_{\bar x} = \bigcap_{x\in f^{-1}(\bar x)}A|_x \qquad \forall \bar x\in \bar X.
$$
As such operations can be met in different areas of math, I've put some tags.

Comment: I've never seen the notation $(f\|\operatorname{id}_Y)$ before. Is that the extension of $f$ to $X\times Y\to\overline X\to Y$ by taking the identity on the $Y$ coordinate?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: good that you've asked - perhaps you can suggest a better notation, as I'm neither in the favor of the current one. Here by $F = f\parallel g$ I mean $F(a,b) := (f(a),g(b))$. It's similar to a product map - but in that case $f$ and $g$ must have the same domain and $F$ will be the function of one variable.